# HashMap needed to get all values

Tags: loops, session, hashmap

i need to gel all values from HashMap, but i always get first row values.

This is my loop code.

```
   Map<String, String> list1 = (Map<String,String>)session.getAttribute("cart");
   Collection c = list1.values();
   Iterator itr = c.iterator();
   while (itr.hasNext()) {
     String kiekis = itr.next().toString();
    String id = itr.next().toString();
    }
```

Comment: You are calling netx() twice in the while loop block

Comment: i want to get data using index, but in this way im getting only one data row

Comment: Use entryset instead,

Answer (score 0):

Use entryset instead, like

```
for(Map<String,String> map : list1){ 
    map.getKey(); ///Key
    map.getValue(); // value
}
```

Comment: in this way i allways getting two numbers. my code : `for(int i = 0;list1.size() > i; i++)
{
 System.out.println(list1.get("id"));
}`